# Python code for Zerodha kite connect api

Tags: python, api

I am using the kite api to automate transacaction like buy,sell,etc.I am extracting data from csv file and putting them in variables . 
Here is the snapshot from the excel file..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hQFv.png)
And here is my code..

```
import csv
from kiteconnect import KiteConnect
import urllib.request
import webbrowser
csvfile = open('../desktop/venkat.csv','r')
csvFileArray = []
for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '\t'):
        csvFileArray.append(row)

header =csvFileArray[0][0].split(',')

kite = KiteConnect(api_key="pgxi3s1pltmrjlkw")
#print(kite.login_url())
data = kite.request_access_token("lqa7c5i65srjnb2wgnfdzoy8dhal4wx0",secret="i345wx7pto3yx2gtb999q531qb2ffkzf")
kite.set_access_token(data["access_token"])
#print(kite.access_token)
for each in csvFileArray[1:]:
        data= each[0].split(',')
        for i in range(len(data)):
            if i==0:
                    exchange=str(data[i])
            elif i==1:
                    tradingsymbol=str(data[i])
            elif i==2:  
                    transaction_type=str(data[i])
            elif i==3:
                    quantity=int(data[i])
            elif i==4:
                    price=int(data[i])
            elif i==5:  
                    product=str(data[i])
            elif i==6:    
                    order_type=str(data[i])
            elif i==7:
                    validity=str(data[i])
            elif i==8:  
                    squareoff_value=int(data[i])
            elif i==9:  
                    stoploss_value=int(data[i])
            elif i==10:  
                    trailing_stoploss=int(data[i])
            else:  
                    variety=str(data[i]) # this is the additional line
        #print(exchange)
        disclosed_quantity=None
        trigger_price=None
        tag=''
        try:
            order_id = kite.order_place(exchange,tradingsymbol,transaction_type,quantity,price,product,order_type,validity,squareoff_value,stoploss_value,trailing_stoploss,variety,disclosed_quantity,trigger_price,tag)
            #print(exchange, tradingsymbol, transaction_type, quantity, price, product, order_type, validity, disclosed_quantity, trigger_price, squareoff_value, stoploss_value, trailing_stoploss, variety, tag)
            #print("Order Placed")
            #print("Order placed. ID is", order_id)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Order placement failed", e.message)
```

It is giving an error that I am not able to solve . Here is the screenshot of the terminal .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ull2E.png)

Also This is the code from the documentation ..

```
def order_place(    self, exchange, tradingsymbol, transaction_type, quantity, price=None, product=None, order_type=None, validity=None, disclosed_quantity=None, trigger_price=None, squareoff_value=None, stoploss_value=None, trailing_stoploss=None, variety='regular', tag='')
```

I am getting an error in the call for order_place() function .
Please take a look and help me . Thanks !

Comment: You might have probably solved this already but just for info, we can specify the parameter names too in case we are not passing the parameters in the specified sequence.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the way you called the function. It's not a good idea to give out post `api_key`, `api_secret`, `request_token` here for everyone to see.

This is what the documentation says:

```
def order_place(self, exchange, tradingsymbol, transaction_type, quantity, price=None, product=None, order_type=None, validity=None, disclosed_quantity=None, trigger_price=None, squareoff_value=None, stoploss_value=None, trailing_stoploss=None, variety='regular', tag='')
```

This is how you called the function:

```
order_id = kite.order_place(exchange,tradingsymbol,transaction_type,quantity,price,product,order_type,validity,squareoff_value,stoploss_value,trailing_stoploss,variety,disclosed_quantity,trigger_price,tag)
```

The function takes the values in order. You passed disclosed_quantity and trigger_price at the end, they should passed after validity.

Try using this:

```
order_id = kite.order_place(exchange,tradingsymbol,transaction_type,quantity,price,product,order_type,validity,disclosed_quantity,trigger_price,squareoff_value,stoploss_value,trailing_stoploss,variety,tag)
```

I can't be sure if this will fix the error without a way to reproduce the error and test the corrected function call myself.

Right now the kiteconnect API is updated to version 3. So the way order placing works is slightly different now.

Comment: I suggest to improve your post:  quote the quoted documentation and to use the code style "{}" for the code parts. Givin' an answer is good but this question .. is not a question .. but the usual, my code is not working! -> translated in -> let's do my job for me. You should try to not help lazy people. ;-) IMHO